# Define The Delete In MySql Documentation Home

Tags: mysql

I see a word in MySql Doucumentation Home.It's

> A deletion is treated internally as an update where a special bit in the row is set to mark it as deleted.

I don't understand the 'a special bit' In this sentence.Why is this not a field?

Comment: https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/bit-binary-digit

Comment: What I want to know is where is the special bit in the row.And Why is not a field.

Comment: Context for the quote: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much background you have in databases. A database uses one of many possible database engines to implement the mysql language. In this case, I think you are looking at the documentation for the InnoDB engine (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html).

I believe the documentation is telling you that behind the scenes, InnoDB is keeping track of some additional information in order to be able to achieve certain database features. They would tell you this to help you understand the engine's behaviors.

The documentation I found is part of InnoDB's transaction and rollback features. If you are interested in being able to "undo" deletions, you should read more about transactions and rollbacks: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: Thanks.I will I will check the documentation according to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this makes sense:

- A database is a collection of tables
- Each table has a number of different columns (fields)
- Each table 'entry' is a row
- A row has data (represented as bytes)
- Bytes are a collection of bits

Each row is stored within a file system as a collection of bytes.
That information includes things like...

- A unique ID
- The data contained within each record

Near the beginning of each row's data is also a single bit representing whether the row is deleted or not.  That bit is set to 0 (off) or 1 (on).

If that bit is set to the appropriate value then MySQL deems the row as "deleted" so that that row can be reused to store a new record without having to grow the tablespace.

Comment: @1756491441 this should be the accepted answer; because it is a clear and concise explanation of your original question.